# How to Change some fields to default or make them null?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, clone

[image]

This is a pop-up when i try to clone a record. **Whenever I clone, I want to change fields to their default value or make them null.** Is there any way to do that using triggers/Other methods?

Comment: why don't you use new record creation option instead of cloning . Or is there some Business use case for this specific process you are using

Comment: reason you don't use new record creation option instead of cloning ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pop-up, If you delete the values of those fields and click 'Save', the values will be automatically set to their default values.

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_default_field_values.htm&type=5):

> The user can change the field’s value but the initial default field
> value is only executed once, during record creation.

If you want to do it via code, you can create a Trigger that will manually set the values you need using `DescribeFieldResult.getDefaultValue()`, note that there are some limitations here (I think it only works for Strings).

Note that resetting the value to null in a trigger will not work (the default values won't reappear):

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert) {
    for (Account a : Trigger.New) {
        a.MyField__c = null;
    }
}
```

That is due to the order of execution, triggers run after the UI was set, so you can't reset it via trigger and expect the UI to add the default value again.